# fillRect or clearRect not working when on this method

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I'm learning HTML 5 and I was trying to make my own Craps game.

Now the idea is that when the "Reset" button is pressed, all values will go back to the default and the canvas will be cleared. However when I do it, the image of the dice are still in the canvas.

Now I don't think there's anything worng with this:

```
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,900,900);
```

but it doesn't work when it's in the reset method. When I put it in other method it works.

Here is the site and code is in it if anyone wants to see:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/90543216/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not call a function in a form environment `reset()`. `reset()` and `submit()` are two special functions which simulate `<input type="reset">`/`<input type="submit">`.

If you rename `reset` to `resetGame`, everything works as intended. However, you should get rid of `<form>` and use `<button>` instead of `<input type="button">` anyway.

Comment: Whoa! I wouldn't have been able to figure that out myself. Thanks! :) By the way, I've been meeting this problem where something doesn't work and I'm not sure what's wrong with the code, sometimes it's a simple type but it's hard to see since you don't get 'compiler errors' unlike other languages. Any tips or ways on proper debugging of javascript code in webpages?

Comment: I usually don't debug JavaScript, but I heard good things about Firebug and Chrome's debugger. I found your error by using `console.log()` in `reset()` and noticed that there's only one log entry instead of one for every click.

Comment: Yea, I'm trying now Firebug but I'm not sure how to use it correctly. Anyway, why should I use the button tag? Is it the newer convention for html5?